# Visual Studio Compile Separate Files

Tags: c, visual-studio, compilation

I am new to Visual Studio and wanted to ask: how can I compile 2 separate files independently? eg. Having Problem1.c(with its main and other functions) , Problem2.c(with its main and other functions) and I want to run them independently, but in VS they are both added to Solution Explorer and create a conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to make a "project" for each.

That sounds like a lot of work for simple work. You can also make one project with one `main` and have that call a function in each of your problem files `.c` in which you implement the problem.

You can use the command line to tell which function (problem) to call, or you can adapt main each time you need to implement a new problem.

That saves you the overhead of creating a project for each problem and lets you quickly start working on implementing a new problem.